# Is $O_n(\mathbb{R})\leq GL_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ A Sub Group?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

Is $O_n(\mathbb{R})\leq GL_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ where $O_n(\mathbb{R})$ are orthonormal matrices.

1. $I_n^t=I^{-1}_n=I_n$ and therefore: $I_n\in O_n(\mathbb{R})$
2. Let $A,B\in O_n(\mathbb{R})$ then we have to prove that $AB^{-1}\in O_n(\mathbb{R})$

We have that if $B\in O_n(\mathbb{R})$ then $B^{-1}=B^{t}\in O_n(\mathbb{R})$ but how can we conclude about  $AB^{-1}\in O_n(\mathbb{R})$?

Can we say that $$(AB^{t})^t=BA^t=BA^{-1}$$

And therefore $AB^{-1}\in O_n(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde No, your proof is shorter, I am trying to proof by the theorem that $H\leq G \iff $ 1.$I_G\in  H$, 2.$A,B\in H$ then $AB^{-1}\in H$

Answer (score 2):

Note that the condition of $A$ being invertible and satisfying $A^t=A^{-1}$ is equivalent to $AA^t = I$. With this it is easy to check the properties of being a subgroup.

1. $II^t = II = I$, hence $I\in O_n$
2. Given $A,B\in O_n$ we have $AA^t=BB^t=I$ and hence
   $$\begin{align}
   (AB^{-1})(AB^{-1})^t&= AB^{-1}(B^{-1})^tA^t\\
   &= AB^{-1}(B^t)^{-1}A^t\\
   &= A(B^t B)^{-1} A^t\\
   &= AA^t\\
   &= I.
   \end{align}$$
   thus $AB^{-1}\in O_n$ as well.